# continueToOriginalDestination does not bring me back to originating page

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

I am trying to sign into my application. First I throw the RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException (this is in a WicketPanel on my BasePage):

```
add(new Link<String>("signin") {
   @Override
   public void onClick() {
       throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(SignIn.class);
   }
});
```

The SignIn Page class contains a form (an inner private class) for the sign in, with the following submit button:

```
add(new Button("signinButton") {

    @Override
    public void onSubmit() {
        final User user = model.getObject();
        final boolean result = MySession.get().authenticate(user);
        if (result) {
            if (!continueToOriginalDestination()) {
                setResponsePage(MySession.get().getApplication().getHomePage());
            }
         } else {
            error("Authentication failed");
         }
    }
 });
```

When this button is clicked and the user is successfully authenticated, I am not redirected to the page where I clicked on the signIn link but instead I stay on the SignIn page? I've tried debugging this, but haven't been able to find out where things go wrong.

I am glad for any hints that lead to my finding the error of my ways.

This is wicket 1.5.1 by the way.

*Small Update* because I got the hint I needed from the answer, there is still a bit of explaining to do. The solution looks like this:

```
add(new Link<String>("signin") {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
         setResponsePage(new SignIn(getPage()));
    }
});
```

The SignIn class gets a constructor that takes a page obviously and I simply set that page as with setResponsePage to return to where I started without all the continueToOriginalDestination and exception throwing.

Comment: Try to implement the `onSubmit`-method in the form, not inside the button.

Comment: Good idea, never thought of it. It didn't solve the problem yet though. But with bernies hint I found a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException` is meant to be used to redirect to an interception page while rendering a page. For example, in the constructor of a Page class `ProtectedPage`, if there is no user signed in, you `throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(SignIn.class)`. When the `SignIn` page calls `continueToOriginalDestination()`, the user is taken back to the original `ProtectedPage` destination.

Your use is not a typical use of `RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException` since you throw it in a link handler. Why don't you do a `setResponsePage(SignIn.class)` directly instead? If you really want to return to the exact page you were on when the "signin" link is clicked, you could also try changing it to:

```
add(new Link<String>("signin") {
   @Override
   public void onClick() {
       setResponsePage(getPage());
       throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(SignIn.class);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining about the actual use of the exception. I had seen it used in such a context and thought the use was broader. But what I did was abuse I guess. So I just stopped using the exception and simply handed the current page as parameter to the SignUp page which I can then use as suggested to set a response page. Thank you!