# Wicket 6 !continueToOriginalDestination: operator ! is undefined

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, migration, wicket-1.5, wicket-6

## Situation

I'm migrating a project from `Wicket 1.5.7` to `Wicket 6.12`, one of the errors I get is explained below.

### Code

```
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit() {
          final String usernameValue = mail.getModelObject();
          //Password is left empty in this particular case
          AuthenticatedWebSession.get().signIn(usernameValue,"");
          if (!continueToOriginalDestination())
          {
            setResponsePage(getApplication().getHomePage());
          }
    }
```

### Error

> This is the error I got when changing wicket versions:  **The operator !
>   is undefined for the argument type(s) void**

*Note: I see this error when hovering over `!continueToOriginalDestination`*

## What did I try

In my search on stackoverflow I came accross this question:
[continueToOriginalDestination does not bring me back to originating page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203087/continuetooriginaldestination-does-not-bring-me-back-to-originating-page)

Also checked this topic on apache wicket:
http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Handling-ReplaceHandlerException-on-continueToOriginalDestination-in-wicket-1-5-td4101981.html#a4115437

*So I changed my code to this:*

```
    @Override
   public void onSubmit() {
       final String usernameValue = mail.getModelObject();
       AuthenticatedWebSession.get().signIn(usernameValue,"");
       setResponsePage(getApplication().getHomePage());
       throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(SignInPage.class);
   }
```

## Question

The old situation nor the code change seem to work in my particular case.

- Maybe it's a small change, is my new code wrong, how should this work?
- Has Wicket changed that much, so that the old code is not supported anymore, or can `!continueToOriginalDestination` be used as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This helps

http://www.skybert.net/java/wicket/changes-in-wicket-after-1.5/

In 1.5, you could do the following to break out of the rendering of one page, go to another page (like login page) and then send the user back to where he/she was:

```
  public class BuyProductPage extends WebPage {
      public BuyProductPage() {
        User user = session.getLoggedInUser();
        if (user  null) {
          throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(LoginPage.class);
        }
      }
  }
```

and then in LoginPage.java have this to redirect the user back to BuyProductPage after he/she's logged in:

```
  public class LoginPage extends WebPage {
    public LoginPage() {
      // first, login the user, then check were to send him/her:
      if (!continueToOriginalDestination()) {
        // redirect the user to the default page.
        setResponsePage(HomePage.class);
      }
    }
  }
```

The method continueToOriginalDestination has changed in Wicket 6, it's now void which makes your code look more magic and less than logic IMO:

```
  public class LoginPage extends WebPage {
    public LoginPage() {
      // first, login the user, then check were to send him/her:
      continueToOriginalDestination();
      // Magic! If we get this far, it means that we should redirect the
      // to the default page.
      setResponsePage(HomePage.class);
    }
  }
```